# Optional Reporting Parameters (is there a better way?)

Tags: sql, database, t-sql, reporting-services

I have a report with 4 parameters. I would like to make them not required. The problem is the conventional approach to do this, creates 16 OR/AND statements. If I were to have 10 not required parameters the SOL statement would be out of control. This works but is there an easier way?

Here is what I have:

**MAIN DATA SET:**

```
select * 
from table 
where 
     table.one = @param1 OR @param1 IS NOT NULL 
     AND.....(etc.etc..)
```

**@param1, @param2,@param3,@param4: (default value null/blank)**

```
Select some_column from any_table UNION SELECT '' as Nothing
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I've always done it is

```
WHERE 
  col1 = isnull(@col1, col1) 
  and col2 = isnull(@col2, col2)
  ...etc
```

So pretty much what you have, with some semantic corrections.

Comment: No - if your parameter is optional then I would assume NULL means they didn't specify a value. Therefore, if the value is NULL, you want to equate the table's column to itself (to return all values).

Comment: Actually, this doesn't work if the values in the table are NULL; and, COALESCE is better to use than ISNULL, since the former is standard.  Here is a better expression:  coalesce(col1, '') = coalesce(@col1, col1, '').